# Assignment from borrowed content

Tags: rust

Consider this trivial piece of code:

```
fn f(&mut self) {
    let ref mut local = &mut self.foo;
}
```

What I wanted to do here was assign `self.foo` to `local` so that I could use `local` in its place. I had to fight a bit with the compiler, though. Instead of `ref mut`, I was trying `&mut`, but the compiler was complaining that it `cannot move out of borrowed content`. Note that `self.foo` does not inherit the `Copy` trait.

From what I understand, the different between `&` and `ref` is that the former accepts a pointer on the right-hand side, while the latter accepts a value. What I find confusing is that `&mut self.foo` looks like a pointer to me. Why is it then that `ref` is correct?

Comment: Does this recent article help?  http://xion.io/post/code/rust-patterns-ref.html

Answer (score 2):

The expression `let ref mut local = &mut self.foo` gives you doble reference i.e. `&mut &mut T`

There are examples of how you can do what you're trying:

```
struct Foo{
    foo:u32,
}

impl Foo{
    fn f(&mut self) {
        // let ref mut local = &mut self.foo;
        // let z:()=local;//found type `&mut &mut u32`
        {
            let ref mut local = self.foo;
            *local = 40;
        }
        println!("{}",self.foo);
        {
            let local = &mut self.foo;
            *local = 41;
        }
        println!("{}",self.foo); 
        {
            let &mut Foo{foo:ref mut local} = self;
            *local = 42;
        }
        println!("{}",self.foo);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut f = Foo{foo:0};
    f.f();
}
```

The `ref` is necessary to obtain references to the fields of a struct when doing pattern matching or destructuring via the `let` binding.

---

> why using `&mut` instead of `ref mut` gives an error?

Expression `let &mut local = self.foo` gives mismatched types error.

Here Rust tries to destructure the value in the right side (`u32`) to some mutable reference (`&mut_`) in the left side.

To make it work you need to write  `let &mut local = &mut self.foo`.

However this is a full equivalent of the `let local = self.foo`

If type of the `self.foo` is **non-copyable** you will get error `E0507` "cannot move out of borrowed content". Causes of this error is perfectly explained in the [Rust Compiler Error Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0507), in the [Rust Book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/references-and-borrowing.html) and in [dozens of answers on StackOwerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=%5Brust%5D%20move%20out%20borrowed%20content)

---

P.S. Highly recommend to read the article on the link posted by @Chris Emerson

Comment: Just for completion, can you talk about why using `&mut` instead of `ref mut` gives an error?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I first thing I tried was `let &mut local = &mut self.foo` and it *didn't* work. The compiler says I can't move out of borrowed content. It makes sense now, but I just wanted it mentioned in your answer because it confused me initially.

Comment: I used type `u32` in my examples. It is __copyable__ type. Apparently you used some __non-copyable__ data type

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention that. Let me update my question. Sorry.

Comment: Anyway first example will work fine with non-copyable types too. There is no safe way to move out non-copyable data from borrowed variable. However you can clone it or use unsafe `mem::replace`